# Using Selenium to select an element with javascript in the href

Tags: c#, selenium, webforms

I have a .NET WebForm and I need to click a link using Selenium and can't use the text content (because of translation issues). How can I identify this element?

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01','')">registration form</a>
```

I have tried the following, which does not work:

```
var element = Driver.FindElementsByXPath($"//*[@href='ctl01']");
```

Comment: Update the question with some more of the `outerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately decided to identify within the `href` attribute by partial string:

```
.FindElementsByXPath($"//*[contains(@href, '{id}')]")
```

This is because putting the whole value of the javascript text into the Selenium call caused it to fail parsing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to look for an id within the xpath, while the element does not contain an id.

In this case, this should work:

```
var element = Driver.FindElementsByXPath($"//a[contains(text(), 'registration form')]");
```

This will only work if all the elements which you are trying to find are links with the text registration form in it.

If you want to find elements on the href, use:

```
var element = Driver.FindElementsByXPath
("//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01','')')]");
```

Comment: You're right - edited to show my actual code includes href, not id. D'oh!

Comment: Ultimately, this answer was the closest. I have posted my final solution.

Comment: Good to see you got through it and glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

try searching for the a href instead of the id like this:
`a[@href='javascript:__doPostBack('ctl01','')']`
with FindElementsByXPath
then on the `var element` try using SendKeys like so:

```
element.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```